# Custom annotation filter Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I see that with Spring boot is really simple create filters. Just follow post like this one https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter

What I have not able to find, is how to create annotations that subscribe specifics endpoints in the controller to one filter.

Something like in Jax-RS it would looks like

```
 @GET
    @Path("jax-rs-single")
    @Reactive(ttlRequest = 2000)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Single getSingle() {
        return Single.just("Hello world single");
    }
```

Where `@Reactive` it would trigger the ReactiveFilter implementation per request.

I also saw the @WebFlow annotation, but it's not what I want. I want to create a library where the consumers decide which filter use, just adding the annotation in the controller.

Any idea how to do something similar with Spring boot/MVC ?

Regards

Comment: I doubt that the filter in Jax-rs is a regular servlet filter. Why because servlet filters can be mapped to URLs or Servlets only. In a Filter it knows nothing about what eventually will handle the request. Unless there is another framework providing this and at configuration time adding this to the filter you will need to write you own processing and registrations.

Comment: Jax-rs provide the possibility to pass to a filter ResourceInfo to get information of the endpoint is invoked.

Comment: Which isn't provided by a default servlet Filter hence it must be an extension or a specific JAX-RS filter. So unless there is some additional framework doing this you need to write It yourself (as provided in one of the answer). And no in Spring MVC there is no solution as that is based on the blocking Servlet API, you might be able to configure something for Spring WebFlux which is the reactive counterpart.

Comment: @paul updated my answer with a second approach

Comment: Thanks a lot man, looks much better

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will try to describe here more about Custom annotation and the processor in Spring.

I don't know what you want or what you need, but I will give an generic example.

You have 2 options:

- BeanProcessor
- HandlerInterceptor

#### BeanProcessor

You need to build 3 things basically: Annotaton, BeanProcessor and a Callback to execute your logic if annotated. Here is an example of it and how it works:

1 - Create the annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD})
@Documented
public @interface Reactive {
    Integer ttlRequest;
}
```

2 - Implement a BeanPostProcessor

```
 @Component 
 public class ReactiveAnnotationProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    private ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableBeanFactory;

    @Autowired
    public ReactiveAnnotationProcessor(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
        this.configurableBeanFactory = beanFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) 
      throws BeansException {
        this.scanReactiveAnnotation(bean, beanName);
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) 
      throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    protected void scanReactiveAnnotation(Object bean, String beanName) {
        this.configureMethodInjection(bean);
    }

    private void configureMethodInjection(Object bean) {
        Class<?> managedBeanClass = bean.getClass();
        MethodCallback methodCallback = 
          new ReactiveMethodCallback(configurableBeanFactory, bean);
        ReflectionUtils.doWithMethod(managedBeanClass, methodCallback);
    } 
}
```

3 - Create the method callback (here is the logic to execute)

```
public ReactiveMethodCallback implements MethodCallback {

    private ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableBeanFactory;
    private Object bean;

    public ReactiveMethodCallback(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory bf, Object bean) {
        configurableBeanFactory = bf;
        this.bean = bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void doWith(Method method) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    if (!method.isAnnotationPresent(Reactive.class)){
      return;
    }
    //YOUR LOGIC HERE
  }

}
```

Here is a good source about annotation processing, it is about FieldProcessing but you can just change the interfaces to implement what you need if you have doubts: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-annotation-bean-pre-processor

[UPDATED] You can also create a HandlerInterceptor instead:

#### HandlerInterceptor

```
public class ReactiveFilterHandlerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws
    Exception {

        if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
            HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
            // Test if the controller-method is annotated with @CustomFilter
            Reactive filter = handlerMethod.getMethod().getAnnotation(Reactive.class);
            if (filter != null) {
                // ... do the filtering, or call the Component for filtering
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And register your handler:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Autowired 
  ReactiveFilterHandlerInterceptor reactiveFilterHandlerInterceptor;

  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(reactiveFilterHandlerInterceptor);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. That’s weird you cannot just use Filter of spring, and you have To do all this mambo Jambo

Comment: Also I would rather avoid Reflection

Comment: I think in the end even the filter you would end up using reflection to check the annotation, unless it happens on compilation time like dagger or micronaut annotations. I will try to think about uaing the filter.

Comment: @paul if you agree and this helped, could you please accept this answer?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly the main problem is how to apply filter based on custom annotation.

So first of all, yes you can use a regular Spring filter (`WebFilter` in case of Spring Webflux or `Filter` in case of Spring MVC), but you'll need to write some custom logic.

To do filtering based on annotation you should:

1. Use `RequestMappingHandlerMapping#getHandlerInternal()` method to retrieve a reference to the method that handles the request (the `getSingle()` in your case)
2. When you manage to retrieve the `HandlerMethod` then you can check if that method has your custom annotation applied with `hasMethodAnnotation(Class<A> annotationType)` method.
3. When you know that, then you can react accordingly: either `chain.doFilter(request, response)` without performing any actions, or apply your custom logic, and then trigger the rest of the filter chain.